# pyspark transform json array into multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the below code to read data from an api where the payload is in json format using pyspark in azure databricks. All the fields are defined as string but keep running into json_tuple requires that all arguments are strings error.

***Schema:***

```
root
 |-- Payload: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ActiveDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessName: string (nullable = true)
```

***JSON:***

```
 {
    "Payload": 
    [
        {
            "ActiveDate": "2008-11-25",
            "BusinessId": "5678",
            "BusinessName": "ACL"
        },
        {
            "ActiveDate": "2009-03-22",
            "BusinessId": "6789",
            "BusinessName": "BCL"
        }
    ]
}
```

***PySpark:***

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.select(F.col('Payload'), F.json_tuple(F.col('Payload'), 'ActiveDate', 'BusinessId', 'BusinessName') \.alias('ActiveDate', 'BusinessId', 'BusinessName'))
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("delta_payload")
```

***Error:***

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'json_tuple(`Payload`, 'ActiveDate', 'BusinessId', 'BusinessName')' due to data type mismatch: json_tuple requires that all arguments are strings;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your schema it looks like the JSON is already parsed, so `Payload` is of `ArrayType` rather than `StringType` containing JSON, hence the error.

You probably need `explode` instead of `json_tuple`:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([{
...     "Payload":
...     [
...         {
...             "ActiveDate": "2008-11-25",
...             "BusinessId": "5678",
...             "BusinessName": "ACL"
...         },
...         {
...             "ActiveDate": "2009-03-22",
...             "BusinessId": "6789",
...             "BusinessName": "BCL"
...         }
...     ]
... }])
>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(Payload,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true),true)))
>>> df.select(explode("Payload").alias("x")).select("x.ActiveDate", "x.BusinessName", "x.BusinessId").show()
+----------+------------+----------+
|ActiveDate|BusinessName|BusinessId|
+----------+------------+----------+
|2008-11-25|         ACL|      5678|
|2009-03-22|         BCL|      6789|
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi @Czaporka, I run into the error `NameError: name 'StructType' is not defined` while trying to use this line of code. `StructType(List(StructField(Report_Entry,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true),true)))`

Comment: Hi @paone, that line is just the output I got after typing `df.schema` in an interactive interpreter session. I included it just to show the schema of my DataFrame. The lines that you should execute are prefixed with `>>> `. Most importantly, you probably need the first one (import `explode`) and the last one with the select.

Comment: Hi @Czaporka, Thank you. That works. But the issue I now encounter is    `df.show(truncate=False)` shows data in a tabular format 
+----------+------------+----------+
|ActiveDate|BusinessName|BusinessId|
+----------+------------+----------+
|2008-11-25|         ACL|      5678|
|2009-03-22|         BCL|      6789|
+----------+------------+----------+                                                                                    delta_tbl results are array           
 `df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("delta_tbl")
  spark.sql("SELECT * FROM delta_tbl LIMIT 1")`

Comment: @paone did you assign the result of the `select` with the `explode` back to `df`? In my code sample, I did `df.select(...).show()` again just to show what that `select` is going to return; but in your actual code you'd need to assign its result to `df` before writing it, i.e. `df = df.select(...); df.write.format(...)...` (like in your original code), or just do `df.select(...).write.format(...)...`.

Comment: Hi @Czaporka, Yes I did, works now. Thank you.